# React Protected Route Not Working with Backend/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, django-rest-framework, react-redux

Hey so my new protected route for users trying to view certain details about their business is not working. The backend verifies if the user is a "member" and if true will let them continue. The backend is sending the correct payload and I can see that in the redux developer tool but the console log is initially undefined. It's not until after the user is redirected back and clicks the link a second time will the console log equal true. I know this is an asynchronous issue but I can't figure it out. I've tried using `setTimeout()` as well but that did not work either.

Protected Route component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { businessDetail } from "../../redux/actions/business";
import { Outlet, Navigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function BusinessRoute (props) {
  const { businessSlug } = useParams();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(businessDetail(businessSlug))

    console.log(business.member)
  }, [])

  const business = useSelector(state => state.business.business_page,)

  return (
    business?.member ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/your-businesses" />
  )
}

export default (BusinessRoute);
```

Redux State:

[image: Redux state]

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait until the `business.member` value is defined before making the determination to either render the protected content via the `Outlet` component or redirect via the `Navigate` component.

```
function BusinessRoute () {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { businessSlug } = useParams();  

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(businessDetail(businessSlug));
  }, [dispatch, businessSlug]);

  const business = useSelector(state => state.business.business_page);

  if (business.member === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  return business.member
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/your-businesses" replace />;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Drew. You have once again come to my rescue

Comment: @SpaceFlightRelated That's me, dev rescuer! Glad to help. Cheers.